# How to subtracte a value from the CURDATE()?

Tags: mysql, date-format

I am trying to get the value of the current day minus five days but i want the result in special format (not the MySQL format) :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB( DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) ,  '%d.%m.%Y' ) , INTERVAL -5
DAY ),  '%d.%m.%Y')
```

I change the format of the curdate() and the format of the result but the current day is:

```
03.09.2013
```

i get the result like the following:

```
25.09.2003
```

can anybody explain that to me what is wrong why i could not get the right result?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should subtract the values in `DATE` *(or compatible)* format, and then convert it to the format you want to receive:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -5 DAY), '%d.%m.%Y')
```

The second issue in your query is that you're subtracting a negative value, witch ends up with adding a value *(for example: `10 - (-5) = 15`)*. You should you use one of the following:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY), '%d.%m.%Y')
```

or

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -5 DAY), '%d.%m.%Y')
```

There is also a little bit shorter way how to write this query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY,  '%d.%m.%Y')
```

### [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/19446/0)

**See also:**

- [`ADDDATE()` function in the official MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: Not the answer to his question.

Comment: @Mihai - I added a little bit of explanation in my answer.